# Is it possible to cancel Ajax-Requests with a custom dialog with Primefaces 3.3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

We want to display a confirmation dialog if a user changes values in a `selectOneMenu`. This works quite good with the browsers native `confirm()` method because it blocks until the user decides. Is there an elegant (preferable client-side) solution to do this with primefaces dialogs so the look is consistent over different browsers?

Current solution:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="som" value="#{foo.item}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{foo.items}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i.name}" itemValue="#{i.value}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" onstart="return confirmChange()" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmChange() {
        return confirm("O'RLY?");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use PrimeFaces' [`<p:confirmDialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf) or even just [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="som" value="#{foo.item}" onchange="confirm.show()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{foo.items}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i.name}" itemValue="#{i.value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirm" message="ORLY?" header="Confirm" severity="alert">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{bean.submit}" process="som" oncomplete="confirm.hide()" />  
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" onclick="confirm.hide()" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Perform the confirmation job in `#{bean.submit}`. You could if necessary abstract this all away with a tag file or a composite component so that it's nicer reuseable.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="som" value="#{foo.item}" onchange="confirm.show()">
    <f:selectItems value="#{foo.items}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i.name}" itemValue="#{i.value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<my:confirmDialog id="confirm" message="ORLY?" action="#{bean.submit}" process="som" />
```

Note that there's no means of "cancelling" ajax requests here. You just don't invoke it until really confirmed.

Comment: That looks good! But isn't returning false from onstart really a cancellation of an ajax request? I'd refer to this post: http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/primefaces-ajax-callbacks/ Currently a setter is invoked automatically when the value changes and this may be cancelled. So in your solution I will invoke the setter always but accept the value only from a dialog. Makes sense but feels like it has to be easier! :)

Comment: Yes, but you wanted a custom HTML confirm dialog, not a standard JS confirm dialog, right? Edit: no, the setter isn't invoked at all on change. I removed the `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. I misinterpreted *"Note that there's no means of "cancelling" ajax requests here."* as *"you cannot"* instead of *"in this solution you do not"*. My apologies!

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for me, it takes the old value from the selectOneMenu instead of the new one

Comment: @JohnB: It indeed doesn't update the confirm dialog with input values before opening as that requirement was nowhere covered by the question in its current form.

Comment: @BalusC: Can you help me to do this, I put it on this answer: ´http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878397/confirmdialog-is-not-taken-the-new-value-of-the-selectonemenu´